# Restful web service not returning XML

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have been trying to get a simple REstful web service working, eventually getting this to talk to a database (via another Java class).

I've started simple, seeing if I can pass in some data and get a response.

The code for the web service is :

```
package com.mystuff.wstest;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("/generic")
public class GenericResource
{

   @Context
   private UriInfo context;

   public GenericResource()
   {
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/data")
   @Produces("application/xml")
   public String getXml(@QueryParam("ctype") String cType, @QueryParam("cdata") String cData)
   {
       return ( "<ret><One>" + cType + "</One><Two>" + cData + "</Two></ret>" );
   }
```

The url to test this is:

```
 http://localhost:8080/WebSvc1/webresources/generic/data?ctype=a\&cdata=b
```

But the returned response in the browser does not show as XML, but simply a "ab" - i.e. it's interpreting the XML as HTML tags.

Testing with wget show this:

```
$ wget -S -q -O - http://localhost:8080/WebSvc1/webresources/generic/data?ctype=a\&cdata=b
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Type: application/xml
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Sun, 10 Aug 2014 12:05:37 GMT
<ret><One>a</One><Two>b</Two></ret>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd say your web service is working correctly, and the browser is mistakenly interpreting the XML as (X)HTML and trying to render it.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: I get the same on Chrome and FF. However, based on your post, I tried on IE and that treats it like XML. Thanks. Update - actually Chrome is OK now too. STrange.

Comment: It works fine for me in: `IE(6.0)`, `Chrome (36.0)` also in `Firefox(31.0)`. It should work for you.